# How to add imageview in ViewFlipper more than 2

Tags: android, imageview, viewflipper

I'm adding viewFlipper in my Project. When I add 2 imageview in viewFlipper everything works correctly but when I add to more than 2 imageview my application doesn't start. How can I fix it ?

** I'm adding 2 image 1.5MB it's running
** I'm adding 3 image 300KB it's not running

I think, it's not about my memory.

If I edit like this, everything works correctly

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sanfransisco"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/eiffel"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

But If I add like this, it doesn't works

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sanfransisco"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/istanbul"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/eiffel"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

Best Regards,

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't start"? is there an error? if yes please post the logcat error

Comment: It's looks like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlW7PVjA7NI and my Logcat just two line;

08-02 16:23:57.375: I/dalvikvm(16119):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-02 16:23:57.375: I/dalvikvm(16119):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)

Comment: Could you also post the code you use exactly when you have more then 2 imageviews?

Comment: I'm edited my post. Could you see it ?

Comment: I can see it but it is correct. Try to clear the project in eclipse and run again the project. Also, for the fadeIn/fadeOut animations you could use @android:anim/fade_in/@android:anim/fade_out (there are default animations)

Comment: I created new project and remove animation, It doesn't work. But if I added two imageview it's running :) I think that's joke :(